# Showing formatted code in a textbox in C#

Tags: c#, windows

Does anyone know how I would show code in a textbox in c#?  I am importing the code from a spreadsheet into sql server.  Then I need to pull the code out of sql server and store it in a textbox but the spacing is off when I display it and it is hard to read.

Is there any controls or functions that help with this?

Any help is much appreciated.

Edit* This is for a windows form application.

Comment: What does the spacing has to do with the text in the `TextBox`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  For example, if I were to post code in this forum I would use code tags to preserve format.  Is there a way I can do that in C#?  even if its not a textbox?

Comment: It seems to be the usual problem with variable width fonts. Set the textbox font to a fixed width font like Consola

Comment: Web or windows app? there's a difference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Windows Form application if you really need some formatting you should use a [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> With the RichTextBox control, the user can enter and edit text. The
>   control also provides more advanced formatting features than the
>   standard TextBox control. Text can be assigned directly to the
>   control, or can be loaded from a rich text format (RTF) or plain text
>   file. The text within the control can be assigned character and
>   paragraph formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Is this for a web application or a Windows application? There are plugins that do just that for web-based apps.

For instance, I use [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) by Alex Gorbatchev. It uses javascript so it's not specific to C# or any other language. You can configure it to color different languages e.g., in your case, SQL.

Comment: Ah thanks for your answer its for a windows application though.  Forgot to specify.